# Is there a way to set the referer in the initial request made by SFSafariViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, webkit, ios9

`SFSafariViewController` is compelling, but has a very simple API that doesn't allow setting any fields on the request it initiates when presented. Are there any clever ways to set the [HTTP referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) header on requests initiated from `SFSafariViewController`?

Comment: Until now, no you can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API for that, unfortunately.

You can check [SFSafariViewControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewControllerDelegate/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SFSafariViewControllerDelegate/safariViewController:didCompleteInitialLoad:) page - all of the delegate methods is post-load handlers.

WKWebView and [WKNavigationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKNavigationDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/WKNavigationDelegate/webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:) is one of possible replacements (iOS 8.0+).

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could think to do this would be to bounce the request off of a web service that you control.

Sadly you can't use anything other than `http` or `https` URLs, so a local file URL won't work (short of listening on a socket on the device).

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't even work. The original request is the only one that can specify the referer, redirects cannot.